# Edit a commit message using source control in Xcode

Tags: git, version-control, xcode4, git-commit

I committed my project using source control in Xcode. After the commit, I realized I forgot to add something to my commit message.

How can I go back and update the commit message?

Comment: Are you using git exclusively through Xcode? Can you use git via the command line?

Comment: Assuming you can use `git` from the command line, its just `git commit --amend`

Comment: I actually ended up using the GitHub application that does the same as the command line just easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually ended up using the GitHub application that does the same as the command line just easier to use.

Comment: how is the command line easier to use? isnt clicking a button better?

Comment: He's saying that the "GitHub application" is "easier to use."